# Serialization with inheritance

Tags: java

I have a class A that I need to serialize, but I can't change its code

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class A (){
   private int i;
   public A (int i) {
     this.i = i;
   }
   public A () {}
}
```

created class B

```
public class B extends A implements Serializable {
   public B (int i) {
     super(i);
   }
}
```

Here I try to write it down and read it

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b1 = new B(10);
    // Serialization and deserialization
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileName");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(b1);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    B b2 = (B) ois.readObject();
    ...
}
```

As a result, I get all zeros. During deserialization, an empty constructor of class A is called and writes 0 to the variable i. But I can't make edits to Class A, how do I beat this?

Comment: Usually `A` should implement `Serializable` as well. Given `B` is extending `A`.

Comment: I can't make edits to Class A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the real problem is that the fields in the (non-serializable) superclass `A` are not being serialized

You can resolve this by adding custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods to `B` that will read and write values of `A`s fields.  In order to access those fields, you need getters and setters ... because a subclass cannot access private fields of its superclass.

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws IOException {
    os.defaultWriteObject();
    os.writeInt(getI());
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
                                                     IOException {
    is.defaultReadObject();
    setI(is.readInt());
}
```

Note that the [Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) says that a `readObject` method *must* call either `defaultReadObject` or `getFields` before reading any additional fields.  Likewise for `writeObject`.

---

If your superclass `A` has multiple fields, then they need to be read and written individually ... in the obvious fashion.

If your superclass `A` does not provide getters and setters for the relevant fields, then you will need to use abstraction breaking reflection to get and set its field values.  At this point, you are (IMO) better off biting the bullet and changing `A` to make it implement `Serializable` ... or replacing it with a class that is more fit for purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try to customize serialization and deserialization in class `B`:

```
        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream aOutputStream) throws IOException
        {
            aOutputStream.defaultWriteObject();
            aOutputStream.writeInt(getI());
        }

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream aInputStream) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
        {
            aInputStream.defaultReadObject();
            setI(aInputStream.readInt());
        }
```

Comment: In fact, there are a lot of fields in Class A. I simplified the code for the question. It turns out that you need to write and read each variable separately?